# Is commit used on the connect or cursor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, commit

The book named "Practical Programming: 2nd Edition" has conflicting code. This is the start of my code:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('stackoverflow.db')    
cur = conn.cursor()
```

To commit, would I use `con.commit()`, `cur.commit()` or are there different times to use each? From the book:

`con.commit()` :

[image: con commit]

`cur.commit()` :

[image: cur.commit()]

[Documentation shows `con.commit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the code? What did you discover?

Comment: Best advice. I'm new to programming, so I always feel like I'm going to mess something up if I write the wrong code ':)
cur.commit does not work. I'll post a solution with details. Thank you for helping me learn more :)

Answer (score 5):

I took unutbu's advice and tried it myself.

Sample code:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
cur = con.cursor()

data = [('data', 3), ('data2', 69)]

cur.execute('CREATE TABLE Density(Name TEXT, Number INTEGER)')

for i in data:
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO Density VALUES (?, ?)', (i[0], i[1]))

cur.commit()
```

PyCharm Run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2018.1/scratches/scratch_2.py", line 13, in <module>
    cur.commit()
AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute 'commit'
```

Error in textbook. `cur.commit()` does not exist.

Thanks unutbu and s3n0

Answer (score 4):

`con.commit()` and `conn.commit()` are the same ... they are created object types ... in both cases they are otherwise named ... important is mainly `.commit()` and not the naming that the programmer has specified

There are object types that use a different name (con and cur - as you asked) to calling the method. You can also use a different name in your code, for example:

```
db = sqlite3.connect('/tmp/filename.db')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE ....
               .... some DB-API 2.0 commands ....
               ")
db.commit()
```

Please check again the webpage https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html . 
You forgot to copy these two lines from the webpage:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
```

And then continuing the code (just copied it):

```
c = conn.cursor()

# Create table
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE stocks
             (date text, trans text, symbol text, qty real, price real)''')

# Insert a row of data
c.execute("INSERT INTO stocks VALUES ('2006-01-05','BUY','RHAT',100,35.14)")

# Save (commit) the changes
conn.commit()

# We can also close the connection if we are done with it.
# Just be sure any changes have been committed or they will be lost.
conn.close()
```

Comment: I was comparing cur. commit() vs con/conn.commit()

Comment: Sorry, but in your question is not fully code from the education book. In the second image https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdc8k.png is there mistake maybe and you may be right. Cursor commit is a mistake I think... the sqlite3 database object may be commited, not the cursor.

Comment: Look here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#connection-objects and https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects There is no object named as .commit for cursor. But for connection is it there.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you're using a specified cursor to commit changes, in your case, it should be cur.connection.commit().
You can always use connect to commit in the end of your code, whether it's named db, or con or conn.
But when your code gets complicated, you'll have different function to do certain operation to the database, if you only use connection commit, when there is a bug, you gonna have a hard time to find which function failed. So you create specific cursor for specific operation, when that failed, the traceback message will show you which specific cursor when wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To @s3n0 & @DanielYu's point they can be handled two different ways.  I had to list these out to better understand the overlap:

## [Connection Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#connection-objects)

```
backup
close
commit
create_aggregate
create_collation
create_function
cursor
enable_load_extension
execute
executemany
executescript
in_transaction
interrupt
isolation_level
iterdump
load_extension
rollback
row_factory
set_authorizer
set_progress_handler
set_trace_callback
text_factory
total_changes
```

## [Cursor objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects)

```
arraysize
close
connection
description
execute
executemany
executescript
fetchall
fetchmany
fetchone
lastrowid
rowcount
setinputsizes
setoutputsize
```